# Is it possible to use VNC / ScreenShare OS X 10.9 Mavericks OSX Server 3.0.1 Local Network User

Tags: macos, server.app, screen-sharing

Quite simply, is it possible to use VNC (Windows) or ScreenShare (OS X) as a local network user?

All users are local network users and when I access the server via Screen Share VNC://LOCAL IP ADDRESS I am prompted for a username/password. When I enter username/password of a local network user I am told "Authentication Failed to 192.168.1.1. Please verify you have entered the correct name and password.

I set up a local account and when entering those details everything works fine.

Surely the ability to use VNC/ScreenShare is available for local network users?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use network accounts (no home folder on the Mac) or mobile accounts (one Home folder in /Users) ? You may be able to add authorization for the VNC/ARD service for mobile accounts with the `kickstart` command :

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users YOURUSERSHORTNAME -privs -all -restart -agent -menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can grant VNC rights to local users in the Sharing Sharing or Remote Management tabs of System Preferences.  Simply having created users on a server does not give them any access, you must assign permissions.